# Kotlin flow combination

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I'm not sure how to go about using Kotlin flows when there is a series of parallel requests which need to converge in the same result.
As an example let's use the scenario where we have two endpoints, one returning a list of userIDs and one returning whether the user is older than 30.

```
fun callEndpoint1(): Flow<List<String>> { 
    // Actual call to server returning a list of N userIDs
    // For simulation purposes it returns the following
    return flowOf(listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
}

fun callEndpoint2(userId: String): Flow<Boolean> { 
    // Actual call to server returning a boolean
    // For simulation purposes it returns the following
    return flowOf(userId.toInt() % 2 == 0)
}

fun calculateTotalPeopleOver30(): Flow<Int> {
    return callEndpoint1().map{ listIds ->
               // wrong approach returning 0, should return 2
               var result = 0
               listIds.forEach{ id ->
                   callEndpoint2(id).map { isOver30 ->
                       if (isOver30) result++
                   }
               }
               result
           }
}
```

This approach is wrong because the variable `result` will be returned before having the chance to store all results coming from the different parallel calls.
Without the chance of having an endpoint able to process a bulk of IDs all together, what would be the correct way to approach the issue?

I found a way to make it work, but it's only by leaking in another class the knowledge of what we need to achieve, which is not what I want.
Just for illustration purposes I include it here

```
fun calculateTotalPeopleOver30(): Flow<List<Boolean>> {
    return callEndpoint1().map { listIds ->
        val result = arrayListOf<Boolean>()
        listIds.forEach { id ->
            result.add(callEndpoint2(id).first())
        }
        result.toList()
    }
}

fun coroutineLauncher(scope: CoroutineScope) {
    scope.launch{
        calculateTotalPeopleOver30()
            .collect { list ->
                println("people over 30 are ${list.filter{it}.size}")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call `callEndpoint2()` inside `listIDs.forEach` if you don't need the ID to call it?

Comment: Also, can you please provide a complete example, with some example input and expected output, so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: you are right @marstran, I updated them accodring to your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because a `Flow` will not do anything until you collect it. It is a lazy construct. This means that this piece of code doesn't actually do anything:

```
listIds.forEach{ id ->
    callEndpoint2(id).map { isOver30 ->
        if (isOver30) result++
    }
}
```

To solve this, you need to collect the `Flow` returned by `callEndpoint2(id)`. You can use the `count`-method to do this, instead of counting manually.

```
val result = listIds.map { id ->
    callEndpoint2(id)
        .count { it }
}.sum()
```

Now, there is another problem with this. The counting will not be performed in parallel. It will finish counting the result of one `callEndpoint2(id)` before continuing with the next.

To do this, you can convert your list of IDs to a `Flow` and use `flatMapMerge` to call `callEndpoint2` concurrently. The default concurrency of `flatMapMerge` is 16, but you can configure this with the `concurrency`-parameter. The resulting code is this:

```
fun calculateTotal(): Flow<Int> {
    return callEndpoint1()
        .map { 
            it.asFlow()
              .flatMapMerge { callEndpoint2(it) }
              .count { it }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @marstran. Indeed I know that flows are cold and they need collection, but I was not aware of the operators to perform the count and sum (or at least I did not figure out to use them as such). For the flatMapMerge I'm still reluctant since it's still a preview API